# Tomar la fecha actual del sistema y verificar que este dentro de un rango determinado para poder entrar a la página (html + js)

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una actividad de crear una pagina cualquiera con html y js y mediante la misma tomar la fecha actual del sistema y verificar que este dentro de un rango determinado para poder entrar a la página, pero por mas que lo intente, no logre hacer funcionar esto ultimo, si alguien me podría ayudar se lo agradecería mucho, adjunte el codigo de la pagina, nada mas me faltaría eso.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Estaciones del año y signo zodiacal</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script>
            // Autor: Ángel Gabriel Torres Gallardo  22 de abril del 2021
            // Actualización  15 de mayo del 2021
            function algoritmo(){
            let dia, mes;
            dia = parseInt (document.formulario1.dia.value);
            mes = parseInt (document.formulario1.mes.value);
            if((dia>=21&&mes==3)||(dia<=20&&mes==4))
                alert('El signo es Aries y la estación es Primavera');
            if((dia>=24&&mes==9)||(dia<=23&&mes==10))
                alert('El signo es Libra y la estación es Otoño');
            if((dia>=21&&mes==4)||(dia<=21&&mes==5))
                alert('El signo es Tauro y la estación es Primavera');
            if((dia>=24&&mes==10)||(dia<=22&&mes==11))
                alert('El signo es Escorpio y la estación es Otoño');
            if((dia>=22&&mes==5)||(dia<=21&&mes==6))
                alert('El signo es G\u00E9minis y la estación es Primavera');
            if((dia>=23&&mes==11)||(dia<=21&&mes==12))
                alert('El signo es Sagitario y la estación es Otoño');
            if((dia>=21&&mes==6)||(dia<=23&&mes==7))
                alert('El signo es C\u00E1ncer y la estación es Verano');
            if((dia>=22&&mes==12)||(dia<=20&&mes==1))
                alert('El signo es Capricornio y la estación es Invierno');
            if((dia>=24&&mes==7)||(dia<=23&&mes==8))
                alert('El signo es Leo y la estación es Verano');
            if((dia>=21&&mes==1)||(dia<=19&&mes==2))
                alert('El signo es Acuario y la estación es Invierno');
            if((dia>=24&&mes==8)||(dia<=23&&mes==9))
                alert('El signo es Virgo y la estación es Verano');
            if((dia>=20&&mes==2)||(dia<=20&&mes==3))
                alert('El signo es Piscis y la estación es Invierno');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fondo.css">
        <h1 align="center">Estaciones del año y signo zodiacal</h1>
        <form name="formulario1">
        <br><br><br>
            <table bgcolor=black border="4" style="text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="dia"><h2><font color=white>Ingrese el dia:</font</h2></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="dia" required="required" step="1" type="number" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="mes"><h2><font color=white>Ingrese el mes:</font></h2></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="mes" required="required" step="1" type="number" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
                            <input value="Procesar" type="button" onclick="algoritmo();" />
                            <input type="reset" value="Limpiar"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br><br>
            <h3 align="center"><font color="black"><b>Autor: Ángel Gabriel Torres Gallardo
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fecha: 23 de Abril del 2021</b></font></h3>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar con esto ya que aun me falta por aprender, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que tiene que ver este codigo con tu pregunta?

Comment: disculpa, es que soy nuevo en esta plataforma, a lo que me refería es que en ese mismo código debo tomar la fecha actual del sistema y verificar que este dentro de un rango determinado para poder entrar a la página. Por ejemplo: la pagina tiene de vigencia 14-mayo-2021  al 18-septiembre-2021. Si se quiere entrar fuera de ese periodo debe mostrar un mensaje de error diciendo que la pagina ya no esta disponible.

Comment: A ver. Si ejecuto el script, entonces a la pagina entro. En tal caso querras redirigir o hacer otra cosa cuando la fecha sea esa. Igual, entiendes que eso es muy facil de falsificar no?

Comment: Si, entiendo que es fácil de falsificar, pero por ahora sería que eso funcionara, y lo que dices sobre redirigir no se me había ocurrido, pero mi problema es que no se como hacer para que la condición se cumpliera, le intente poner date o time para tomar el tiempo actual y con la condición if lograr que funcione lo pedido, pero no funciono, por eso necesito ayuda en eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener la fecha actual del objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) usando `new Date()`:

```
fechaActual = new Date()
```

El método [setFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) permite asignar una fecha especifica a una instancia de Date()

```
  const fecha1  = new Date()
  fecha1.setFullYear(año, mes, dia)
```

Y para comparar la fechas usas los operadores <, >, <= , etc..

Usando esto puedes crear una función que compare la fecha actual con las fechas mínima y máxima del rango que deseas. Y en base al resultado mostrar el error.

Aquí he editado tu código con la función y una manera muy sencilla y probablemente no la mejor para mostrar el error:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Estaciones del año y signo zodiacal</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
           
          
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fondo.css">
          
          
              <script >
                // Autor: Ángel Gabriel Torres Gallardo  22 de abril del 2021
                // Actualización  15 de mayo del 2021
                function algoritmo(){
                let dia, mes;
                dia = parseInt (document.formulario1.dia.value);
                mes = parseInt (document.formulario1.mes.value);
                if((dia>=21&&mes==3)||(dia<=20&&mes==4))
                    alert('El signo es Aries y la estación es Primavera');
                if((dia>=24&&mes==9)||(dia<=23&&mes==10))
                    alert('El signo es Libra y la estación es Otoño');
                if((dia>=21&&mes==4)||(dia<=21&&mes==5))
                    alert('El signo es Tauro y la estación es Primavera');
                if((dia>=24&&mes==10)||(dia<=22&&mes==11))
                    alert('El signo es Escorpio y la estación es Otoño');
                if((dia>=22&&mes==5)||(dia<=21&&mes==6))
                    alert('El signo es G\u00E9minis y la estación es Primavera');
                if((dia>=23&&mes==11)||(dia<=21&&mes==12))
                    alert('El signo es Sagitario y la estación es Otoño');
                if((dia>=21&&mes==6)||(dia<=23&&mes==7))
                    alert('El signo es C\u00E1ncer y la estación es Verano');
                if((dia>=22&&mes==12)||(dia<=20&&mes==1))
                    alert('El signo es Capricornio y la estación es Invierno');
                if((dia>=24&&mes==7)||(dia<=23&&mes==8))
                    alert('El signo es Leo y la estación es Verano');
                if((dia>=21&&mes==1)||(dia<=19&&mes==2))
                    alert('El signo es Acuario y la estación es Invierno');
                if((dia>=24&&mes==8)||(dia<=23&&mes==9))
                    alert('El signo es Virgo y la estación es Verano');
                if((dia>=20&&mes==2)||(dia<=20&&mes==3))
                    alert('El signo es Piscis y la estación es Invierno');
                }
            </script> 
          
          
        </head>
        <body>

    <!-- Editado -->
          <div id="error">
            
            ERROR : La página ya no esta disponible
          </div>
          
           <div id="home">
             
            <h1 align="center">Estaciones del año y signo zodiacal</h1>
            <form name="formulario1">
            <br><br><br>
                <table bgcolor=black border="4" style="text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="dia"><h2><font color=white>Ingrese el dia:</font</h2></label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="dia" required="required" step="1" type="number" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="mes"><h2><font color=white>Ingrese el mes:</font></h2></label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="mes" required="required" step="1" type="number" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
                                <input value="Procesar" type="button" onclick="algoritmo();" />
                                <input type="reset" value="Limpiar"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                <h3 align="center" ><font color="black"><b>Autor: Ángel Gabriel Torres Gallardo
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fecha: 23 de Abril del 2021</b></font></h3>
            </form>
             <div>
           

    <!-- Editado , agregue el script al final de body para evitar errores -->
             <script>
               const errorDiv = document.getElementById("error")
               const homeDiv = document.getElementById("home")
               
               errorDiv.style.display = "none"
               homeDiv.style.display = "none"
                  
               function dateWhitinRange(min, max){
                 const currentDate = new Date() 
                 const minDate = new Date()
                 const [minDay, minMonth, minYear] = min.split("/")   
                 minDate.setFullYear(minYear, minMonth - 1 , minDay)
            
                const maxDate = new Date() 
                const [maxDay, maxMonth, maxYear] = max.split("/")   
                 maxDate.setFullYear(maxYear, maxMonth - 1 , maxDay)
               
                 if(currentDate >= minDate && currentDate <= maxDate){
                    return true
                 }
                  return false
               }
             //aqui cambias el rango de las fechas   
               if(dateWhitinRange("14/8/2021","18/09/2021")){
                 errorDiv.style.display = "none"
                 homeDiv.style.display = "block"
               }else{
                 errorDiv.style.display = "block"
                 homeDiv.style.display = "none" 
                 
               }
                 
               </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio de mucho bro